# Understanding Bitwise Operations in This Function

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

For the sake of simplicity, let's just assume the integer I am passing to this function is `9` which is `1001` in binary.

It has been my goal for a while now to write my own integer to binary function in `C`. The way I used to figure out binary values for number in shorthand was as followed (using `9` as mentioned above):

```
9 / 2 = 4.5 (remainder)            = 1
4 / 2 = 2   (no remainder)         = 0
2 / 2 = 1   (no remainder)         = 0
1 / 1 = 1   (remainder)            = 1
```

So if you reverse the `1 0 0 1` we get you will have the binary value of `9` which is still `1 0 0 1`.

But then after looking over this site I found that the binary value of an integer can be found with some "simple" bitwise arithmetic. I found a function on another post on this site and adapted it into a function of my own:

```
char *itob(int integer)
{
    char *bin = 0X00, *tmp;
    int bff = 0;
    while(integer)
    {
        if(!(tmp = realloc(bin, bff + 1)))
        {
            free(bin);
            printf("\nError! Memory allocation failed while building binary string.");
            return 0x00;
        }
        bin = tmp;
        if(integer & 1) bin[bff++] = '1';
        else bin[bff++] = '0';
        integer >>= 1; 
    }
        bin[bff+1] = 0x00; 
    return bin;
}
```

Here is how I understand what is going on as well as my questions (that appear as comments)

```
1001 & 1 = 1 so put a 1 into the buffer //what is & doing that makes it equate to 1? Is it because the first digit in that sequence is a 1?
shift the bits in 1001 to the right one time
0010 & 1 != 1 so move a 0 into the buffer //same question as before is & just looking at the 0 because it is the first digit in the sequence?
shift the bits in 0010 to the right one time
0100 & 1 != 1 so move a 0 into the buffer //same question as before
shift the bits in 0100 to the right one time
1000 & 1 = 1 so put a 1 into the buffer //same question as before (at this point I'm thinking my theory is correct but I'm still not entirely sure)
shift the bits in 1000 to the right one time
loop ends
```

So as mentioned in my comments this is what I believe is going on in my program but I'm not 100% sure. Also I'm not sure if this is the best way to be even converting decimal to binary. (I'm already aware that if `integer` were for whatever reason to be a `0` I would eventually be trying to dereference a `NULL pointer` when trying to free the memory allocated by `itob()` along with a few other hiccups) But besides the questions that I already asked earlier is there a better method or more appropriate way to do this conversion?

Comment: 1) On return of your function, the bin string will not be bul-terminated. 2) do you realise that the string will be in reversed order (low bit is on the left side) ? 3) unsigned types are nicer wrt to bit-twiddling.

Comment: You seem to have written the number little-endian, so where you write "right", it looks like "left".

Comment: Looks to me like your trick at the top should be dividing `1/2`, not `1/1`, and the results from each division should produce the reversed digits. `42%2=0, 21%2=1, 10%2=0, 5%2=1, 2%2=0, 1%2=1` produces `101010`, which is 42b.

Comment: @Jens yes I deleted my comment I somewhat had `realloc(x, 0)` in mind.

Comment: @ouah, `realloc(x, 0)` may be implementation-defined, but works as expected always.

Comment: @wildpasser fixed the null ptr part, and I was planning later on flipping the string, and do you mean instead of using an `int` I should be using an `unsigned int` ?

Comment: @eq See the comments here https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MEM31-C.+Free+dynamically+allocated+memory+exactly+once and you will see different behaviors for widely used systems.

Comment: point 3 was only a hint. It can be done without flipping (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10322142/905902 ; it prints to a file but can easily be modified to target a string)

Comment: @ouah, I'm very well aware of all the possible behaviours on conforming implementations. Furthermore, I am of the opinion that in this regard the CERT site has come to the wrong conclusions about what a conforming `realloc` should not do in this case.

Comment: @eq I was addressing your comment (that you deleted) where you said: *realloc(x, 0) may be implementation-defined, but works as expected always* This is wrong as major implementations show different behaviors and this is a known problem. And of course I was only referring to the comments of the CERT document where people showed different behaviors on the implementation they tested; I was not referring to the CERT content itself.

Comment: @ouah, that comment's still up there; "works as expected" refers to the return value of `realloc(x, 0)` (you can't dereference it but you can `free` it in all implementations). I *did* delete another comment (as it was bordering off-topic), in which I suggested that all conforming implementations of `realloc` should actually `free` the first argument if the second one was zero, regardless of the return value (i.e. some implementations cannot signal an error in this case, but with them the operation *can't* fail.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the sequence of tests and shifts is

```
1001 & 1 => 1   then shift right
 100 & 1 => 0   "
  10 & 1 => 0   "
   1 & 1 => 1   "
```

The resulting integer 0 makes the loop terminate. So what this does is test each bit starting with the least significant bit and *append* a 0 or 1 in the buffer. That I'd say is backwards because when printed as a string the bit sequence is reversed from the one used most often, where the least significant bit is the rightmost one.

Comment: I like this answer a lot, I just want to wait to see a few other answers before accepting it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

thats seems correct reasoning

the only things is the function above gives the binary results back in reverse this is possibly not wanted...

you will not spot this with number 9 (1001) as its binary representation is the same both ways, but you will with the number 4 (0100)

Answer (score 1):

Modelled after the one in my link. Untested, but should be allright.

```
char * bit2str(unsigned int num ) 
{

    unsigned int bit,pos;
    char *dst;

    dst = malloc(1+CHAR_BIT*sizeof bit) ;
    if (!dst) return NULL;

    for(pos=0,bit = 1u << (CHAR_BIT*sizeof bit -1); bit; bit >>= 1 ) {
         dst[pos++] = num & bit ? '1' : '0' ;
    }
    dst[pos] = 0;
    return dst;
}
```